# How to create a lite DTO from existing DTO in java?

Tags: java

I have a dto, say `MyDto` having 10 fields in it. I want to create a light version of that dto with 3 fields only.
I tried this: Created a new object and copy required fields from old object to new object, and set other fields to null.
I do not prefer to make a new light dto with 3 fields only. What are the approaches I can follow here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem. In my case I used ModelMapper in this way.
In the class that needs mapping:

```
@Autowired private ModelMapper modelMapper;

...

public LiteDTO convertToLiteDTO() {
  MyDTO myDTO = new MyDTO();
  return modelMapper.map(myDTO, LiteDTO.class);
}
```

And, to configure ModelMapper in the application:

```
// MyBEConfig.java
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

...

@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
  return new ModelMapper();
}
```

To install ModelMapper with Maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

You necessarily need another DTO in "lite" version. You can't do otherwise, I think.